# Computing camera vectors from image plane using distortions

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, camera, camera-calibration

I'm trying to use a camera model to reconstruct images one could have taken with certain cameras and their (extrinsic/intrinsic) parameters. This I don't have any problems with. Now I want to add distortions as they are described in [OpenCV](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/dc/dbb/tutorial_py_calibration.html)(seems to be the reference model).

The goal is to get a vector for every pixel in the camera grid which I can then use to determine the point it reaches on a surface (i.e. a plane with distance 1 to the camera). Sadly there only seems to be a function for the other direction, being given a point in the world I can compute the corresponding point in the image plane. This method is called [projectPoints()](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html#ga1019495a2c8d1743ed5cc23fa0daff8c).

Is there an inverse function of this? I can't seem to find one or a different reliable method/python module.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: You should be able to project the other way so long as you project all points to some common plane such as the Z=0 ground plane. 2D to 3D projection only works with a model of the scene (or in simple situation the ground plane)

Comment: I want to know this too.
Since the camera model has a complicated shape, I cannot derive the inverse function, and have to use some iterative method to estimate the lay direction.

Comment: @fmw42 You are right, I do want to project the points onto a plane with a fixed distance, after that I can get to the (normed) vectors. I added that to the question, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay,
I've read up a bit and it seems like there is no closed form solution at all for this direction! I do solve it now by iteratively approximating the solution. I only use 5 distortion coefficients, but it should be possible to extend that to more. The first guess is simply the undistorted vectors.

This is the code I use and it is reasonable fast:

```
def distort(D, coeff, th=10e-7, MAXITER=40):
    undistorted = D
    k1, k2, p1, p2, k3 = coeff
    
    done = True
    i    = 0
    while(done):
        undistorted_old = undistorted
        xn, yn = undistorted
        xn2  = np.square(xn)
        yn2  = np.square(yn)
        r2   = xn2 + yn2
        r4   = np.square(r2)
        r6   = r4 * r2
        xyn2 = 2 * xn * yn
    
        # radial and tangential distortions
        DR = np.tile((1 + k1*r2 + k2*r4 + k3*r6), (2,1))
        DT = np.array([p1*xyn2 + p2*(r2 + 2*xn2), p2*xyn2 + p1*(r2 + 2*yn2)])
        
        # Update
        undistorted = (D-DT) / DR
       
        # calculate error
        error = undistorted_old - undistorted
        if ((np.sum(np.square(error)) < th) or (i==MAXITER)):
            done=False
        i=i+1
    
    return undistorted
```

Hope that helps!