# How can I obtain real world point from intrinsic and extrinsic parameters of camera?

Tags: opencv, camera-calibration

I'm using OpenCV for measure object length using camera.(The object is rely on plane)
For camera calibration, I used checker board.
Here's my approach in pseudo code

```
// position array of checker corners in real world coordinate
3d_checker_position 

// possition array of checker corners in image coordinate
2d_checker_position

// find camera matrix, distortion coefficients, 
// camera rotation vector, camera translation vector
camera_mat, dist_coeffs, rvec, tvec = cv.calibrateCamera(3d_checker_position, 2d_checker_position)

// 3D -> 2D
test_2d_checker_position 
  = cv.projectPoints(3d_checker_position, rvec, tvec, camera_mat, dist_coeffs)
// test_2d_checker_position == 2d_checker_position

// 2D -> 3D
test_3d_checker_position 
  = what_function_should_I_use(2d_checker_position, rvec, tvec, camera_mat, dist_coeffs)
```

How to implement `what_function_should_I_use`, or is there any function in OpenCV?

### EDIT 23.04.07

For fully understanding of converting world to image coordinate, I firstly implemented 3D -> 2D by my hand. This is based on below pinhole model equation.

```
sP = I * E * W
```

where `P` is 2 channel (x,y) image point, `I` is intrinsic parameter matrix(camera matrix), `E` is extrinsic parameter matrix(transformation), and `W` is 3 channel (x, y, z) world point.
Below is implementation code from 3D to 2D. `s` is weighted factor for converting homogeneous coordinate to image coordinate.

```cpp
// Firstly, assumed that intrinsic parameters(camera matrix), 
// extrinsic parameters(rotation and translation vector), 
// and distortion parameters are pre-calculated from 
// cv::calibrateCamera function.
cv::Mat intrinsic; // (3x3)
cv::Mat rvec; // (3x1)
cv::Mat tvec; // (3x1) 
std::vector<float> distortion;
// ...

// Secondly, make a extrinsic matrix which is [R | t].
cv::Mat extrinsic= cv::Mat(cv::Size(4, 3), CV_64F);
cv::Mat rot_mat;
cv::Rodrigues(rvec, rot_mat);
rot_mat.copyTo(extrinsic(cv::Rect(0, 0, 3, 3)));
tvec.copyTo(extrinsic(cv::Rect(3, 0, 1, 3)));

// Thirdly, make a pinhole camera model matrix 
// by merging intrinsic and extrinsic parameters.
cv::Mat pinhole_model = intrinsic * extrinsic;


// Finally, convert 3D point to 2D point.

cv::Mat world_point_homogeneous = cv::Mat(cv::Size(1, 4), CV_64F);
world_point_homogeneous.at<double>(0, 0) = world_point.x;
world_point_homogeneous.at<double>(1, 0) = world_point.y;
world_point_homogeneous.at<double>(2, 0) = world_point.z;
world_point_homogeneous.at<double>(3, 0) = 1;

cv::Mat projected_homogeneous 
  = pinhole_model * world_point_homogeneous;

// Convert homogeneous coordinate to image coordinate.
// This equals dividing 's' from 'P' in the above equation.
const double w = projected_homogeneous.at<double>(2, 0);
cv::Point2d image_point;
image_point.x = projected_homogeneous.at<double>(0, 0) / w;
image_point.y = projected_homogeneous.at<double>(1, 0) / w;
```

**Result**
The above code do convert 3D point to 2D point which is very closing to the result of `cv::projectPoints()`.

**Problem**

1. When and how the `distortion` parameters are applied to the process?
2. Back to the origin question, I need the `w` factor(in the equation, `s`) before converting 2D point to 3D point. How can I obtain it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74687278/

Comment: I think OpenCV don't have a function to do it. May be usable one is `undistortPoints`  to do `2D -> undistorted 2D -> 3D`.

Comment: Use solvePnp with the intrinsics (gives you the 3D position in camera system) and transform the result with the extrinsics of the camera.

Comment: But this only works if you know the object points and object geometry. A single arbitrary point can't be reprojected to its final 3D because it could be anywhere on a full ray.

Comment: The title said "from intrinsic and extrinsic parameters"(not from only intrinsic), so ray is enough. (Object is plane and extrinsic will be between camera and the plane)

Comment: solvePnp() returns extrinsics(rvec and tvec) but these are also returned from calibateCamera().

Comment: 3d to 2d projection model is described in OpenCV's reference manual.  Refer "Detailed Description" of https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html

Comment: As already commented, you can obtain ray. not point. In other word, the scale factor can not be obtained without some additional information, in principle. And in your case, I think you have the useful info about measurement target.

Comment: You're right. In my case, the 3D object is rely on the plane where the checker board too, and I set all corners' z of checker pattern to 0 when calibrating the camera. This means I can obtain the scale factor (all z of the object point is 0). I will update my solution soon. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I implemented the solution. As [@fana](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18362054/fana) mentioned, the 3D point cannot be obtained from 2D if it's z is not specified. In my case, the target object in a image lies parallel to the same plane as the checker board, which means the z value is the same as the z of checker board when camera calibration is performed.
Specifically, 2D point is converted to 3D by following pinhole camera model formula.
[image]

where (u,v) is point in image coordinate, (X, Y, Z) is point in world coordinate, the left matrix is intrinsic parameters, and the right matrix is extrinsic parameters.
Simply, calling the product of intrinsic and extrinsic matrix as P,
[image]

since Z is a constant(in this case 0), a simultaneous linear equation for X and Y is established.

```cpp
// Assume world z is 0
std::vector<cv::Point3d> unproject(
    const std::vector<cv::Point2d>& points,
    cv::Mat rvec, cv::Mat tvec,
    cv::Mat& intrinsic,
    const std::vector<float>& distortion) {

  // Reconstruct pinhole-camera model
  cv::Mat transformation = cv::Mat(cv::Size(4, 3), CV_64F);
  cv::Mat rot_mat;
  cv::Rodrigues(rvec, rot_mat);
  rot_mat.copyTo(transformation(cv::Rect(0, 0, 3, 3)));
  tvec.copyTo(transformation(cv::Rect(3, 0, 1, 3)));
  cv::Mat new_intrinsic = cv::getOptimalNewCameraMatrix(intrinsic, distortion, cv::Size(800, 600), 0);
  cv::Mat pinhole_model = new_intrinsic * transformation;

  std::vector<cv::Point3d> world_points(points.size());
  for (int i = 0; i < points.size(); i++) {
    const double a = pinhole_model.at<double>(2, 0) * points[i].x - pinhole_model.at<double>(0, 0);
    const double b = pinhole_model.at<double>(2, 1) * points[i].x - pinhole_model.at<double>(0, 1);
    const double c = pinhole_model.at<double>(0, 3) - pinhole_model.at<double>(2, 3) * points[i].x;
    const double d = pinhole_model.at<double>(2, 0) * points[i].y - pinhole_model.at<double>(1, 0);
    const double e = pinhole_model.at<double>(2, 1) * points[i].x - pinhole_model.at<double>(1, 1);
    const double f = pinhole_model.at<double>(1, 3) - pinhole_model.at<double>(2, 3) * points[i].y;

    double world_x, world_y;
    world_y = (a * f - c * d) / (a * e - b * d);
    world_x = (c - world_y * b) / a;
    world_points[i].x = world_x; 
    world_points[i].y = world_y;
    world_points[i].z = 0;
    std::cout << "image point " << points[i] << " to " << world_points[i] << std::endl;
  }
  return world_points;
}
```

The `cv::getOptimalNewCameraMatrix` function, which updates the intrinsic matrix through the distortion coefficients, has not been verified to work properly in this solution.